# Multiple Wpf clients + SQL Server database concurrency issue

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework-core, multi-user

I have a WPF application working on multiple client PCs with EF Core connecting to a single SQL Server.

When I retrieve transaction number, I count the transaction table records and add one to it.

My issue is when two clients request transaction number at the same time, they get the same transaction number.

Any help regarding this issue well be much appreciated.

```
public async Task<Response<PassportOutputModel>> CreateAsync(PassportInputModel model)
{
    if (!await _validation.IsCorrectAsync(model, EnumPermission.AddPassport))
        return _validation.Response; 

    var number = await UnitOfWork.Passports.GetLastPassportNumberAsync();  

    var passport = Mapper.Map<Passport>(model);

    passport.Number = number;

    await UnitOfWork.Passports.AddAsync(passport);
    await UnitOfWork.CompleteAsync();

    return Response.SuccessCreate(Mapper.Map<PassportOutputModel>(passport));
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason you are not using an auto-incrementing `IDENTITY` column

Comment: Say I have a table which uses an int auto identity as a primary key it is sporadically skipping increments, for example:

1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1004, 1005

Comment: One word of advice: ***DON'T DO THIS YOURSELF!!!!*** Stop wasting your time on trying to come up with a solution - use the ones you have - `IDENTITY` or `SEQUENCE` in the database.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice ... but I am back to scratch ... it's the gaps problem ... this is someone's reply. You should be aware none of these workarounds assure no gaps.  This has never been guaranteed by IDENTITY as it would only be possible by serializing inserts to the table.  If you need a gapless column you will need to use a different solution than either IDENTITY or SEQUENCE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A number of fields are entered at the same time without duplicating, gaping, or jumping.

1- Trigger to automatically add One Number after each Insert process .

2- Indexing number to avoid duplicating and make the process smooth and fast.]

[14_Record_In_Same_Time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4zhC.png)